# how to set rounded corner for a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to set rounded corner for a UITextView ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

fist import the file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and then set the property of your text view

```
yourTextViewName.layer.cornerRadius = kCornerRadius;
```

where `kCornerRadius` is a constant you set as a radius for corner

Comment: I've got an error "use of undeclared identifier kCornerRadius"

Answer (score 5):

Try this it will work for sure

you have to import

```
QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h


UITextView* txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
txtView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
txtView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I define an category class for UITextView in .h:

```
@interface UITextView (RoundedCorner)
-(void) roundedCornerDefault;
-(void) roundedCornerWithRadius:(CGFloat) radius
                borderColor:(CGColorRef) color
                borderWidth:(CGFloat) width;
@end
```

and the implementation class:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "UITextView+RoundedCorner.h"

@implementation UITextView (RoundedCorner)

-(void) roundedCornerDefault {
    [self roundedCornerWithRadius:10 
                      borderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor] 
                      borderWidth:1];
}

-(void) roundedCornerWithRadius:(CGFloat) radius
                    borderColor:(CGColorRef) color
                    borderWidth:(CGFloat) width {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
self.layer.borderColor = color;
self.layer.borderWidth = width;
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
@end
```

Example to use it:

```
#import "UITextView+RoundedCorner.h"
...
[self.myTextView roundedCornerDefault];
```

Comment: This question was posted a long time back.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Work for me as below code and step

1. create textView var

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var currentAddressOutlet: KMPlaceholderTextView!
   ```
2. create this function

   ```
   private func setBorderForTextView() {
   self.currentAddressOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
   self.currentAddressOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
   self.currentAddressOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 5
   }
   ```
3. call above function in your viewDidLoad

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   setupTable()
   setBorderForTextView()
   }
   ```
4. Result is here

[image]