# Round corners to textview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set rounded corner for a UITextView ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922986/how-to-set-rounded-corner-for-a-uitextview)

How can we give round corners to the textview in iPhone.

Please help

Comment: The "related questions"/SO search box algos do seem to have dropped the ball in this case. The question selected as a duplicate doesn't come up till the end of the second page of searching on the title of this question, despite that it is, to a human, clearly a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all those who are still searching

you have to import

```
QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h


UITextView* txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
txtView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
txtView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```